# D3 x axis value stacked on the left

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I've tried to make a simple line chart.
The x axis will show 10,100,1000 etc' values
For some reason I get all the values stacked on the left side of the x axis instead of spreading them equally on the axis.

```
var data = [
    {views:10, odds: 56},
    {views:100, odds: 64},
    {views:1000, odds: 81},
    {views:10000, odds: 95},
    {views:100000, odds: 99},
    {views:1000000, odds: 99},
    {views:10000000, odds: 100},
];

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([
    d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.views; }), 
    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.views; })
])
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([
    d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.odds; }), 
    d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.odds; })
])
.range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(7)
    .tickValues(data.map((d)=>{ return d.views; }));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(7);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.views); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.odds); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/guy_l/77agq0hz/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. They are not "stacked" on the left side, it's just a math problem: each value of x is just 10% of the next value! Keep in mind that your domain goes from 10 to 10 million, so the points would never be equally spread: 90% of your domain is just the space between the 6th and the 7th point.

You can change the scale for an ordinal one or, if you want to keep it quantitative, you need a logarithmic scale here:

```
d3.scale.log();
```

Check your updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/v17cpqdk/